# std::map with key as templated structs with enum member

Tags: c++, templates, enums, stdmap, non-type

I would like to make my app’s `std::map`s’ keys not be `int`s, but rather be more strongly typed as templated non-type `enum`s defined as a member of a `struct`. The first program below shows the concept of how my app currently uses `map`s. It compiles and runs ok.

```
#include <map>

template< int >
struct NummedMap
{
  typedef std::map< int, NummedMap > NumableMap;

  NummedMap() {}

  NumableMap numableMap;
};

int main()
{
  NummedMap< 3 > numableMap3;
  NummedMap< 4 > numableMap4;
  numableMap3.numableMap[ 3 ] = numableMap3;
  numableMap4.numableMap[ 4 ] = numableMap4;

  return 0;
}
```

The second program shows how I would like to program my app’s `map`s, but I am missing some concepts regarding non-type templates and why an `< enum EnumT >` is different from a POD `int`.

```
#include <map>

struct Enums1 // a struct containing one kind scoped enums
{ 
  enum class Action
  {
    AAAA,
    BBBB
  };
};

struct Enums2 // a struct containing another kind scoped enums
{
  enum class Action
  {
    CCCC,
    DDDD
  };
};

template< enum EnumT >
struct EnummedMap // a struct containing a map whose key is non-type templateable
{
  typedef std::map< EnumT, EnummedMap > EnumableMap; // error C2065: 'EnumT': undeclared identifier

  EnummedMap() {}

  EnumableMap enumableMap;
};

int main()
{
  EnummedMap< Enums1::Action > enummedMap1; // error C2993: illegal type for non-type template parameter 
  EnummedMap< Enums2::Action > enummedMap2; // error C2993: illegal type for non-type template parameter 
  enummedMap1.enumableMap[ Enums1::Action::AAAA ] = enummedMap1; // error C2678: binary '[': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type
  enummedMap2.enumableMap[ Enums2::Action::CCCC ] = enummedMap2; // error C2678: binary '[': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type

  return 0;
}
```

I don’t understand why `EnumableMap`‘s key is undeclared, or why for example `Enums1::Action` does not function roughly like an `int` key.

Comment: what on earth are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `be more strongly typed` in a large program translates into greater program clarity, better error checking and in general easier code maintenance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template< enum EnumT >
struct EnummedMap // a struct containing a map whose key is non-type templateable
{
  typedef std::map< EnumT, EnummedMap > EnumableMap;
```

A non-type template parameter (in this case an old-style enum), is a single value, and by definition is not a type, but std::map expects the Key to be a type, not a value.  To make this work, change "enum" to "typename":

```
template<typename EnumT > // << *** HERE ***
struct EnummedMap // a struct containing a map whose key is non-type templateable
{
    typedef std::map< EnumT, EnummedMap > EnumableMap; 
    EnummedMap() {}

    EnumableMap enumableMap;
};
```

However, this allows for non-enum types.  If you want to prevent all uses EXCEPT for enum types, you can use a static_assert:

```
#include <type_traits>
//...
template<typename EnumT>
struct EnummedMap 
{
    static_assert(std::is_enum_v<EnumT>); // c++17
    //static_assert(std::is_enum<EnumT>::value, ""); // c++11

    typedef std::map< EnumT, EnummedMap > EnumableMap;
    EnummedMap() {}

    EnumableMap enumableMap;
};
```

Then it won't compile if a non-enum is passed as the template parameter.